# Pandas corelation in Django

Tags: python, django, pandas, correlation

guys i am a beginner in programming and I desperately need your help. I am trying to develope a webapp using Django. I have created a HTML form in my index.html file. In my views.py I am trying to use the corr() fundtion of Pandas but every time it says `Empty DataFrame`

index.html

```
<form id='form' name='form' method="post" action="">
        {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="Col 1">col 1</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="col1" name="col1">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="Col 2">col 2</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="col2" name="col2">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="Col 3">col 3</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="col3" name="col3">
        </div>

        <div class="form-group col-md-2">
            <label for="Col 4">col 4</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="col4" name="col4">
        </div>
    </div>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" id='predict' name='predict'>Run forecast</button> 
    </form>
```

views.py

```
def index(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        
        col1 = request.POST.get('col1')
        col2 = request.POST.get('col2')
        col3 = request.POST.get('col3')
        col4 = request.POST.get('col4')
        
        data = {'X':[col1, col2], 'Y':[col3, col4]}
        df = pd.DataFrame(data)
        x = df.corr()
        print(x)
        return render(request, 'corelation.html')

    else:
        return render(request,'index.html')
```

Every time I run this code it returns `Empty DataFrame` in terminal. However if I replace col1, col2 with actual numbers it shows the desired result.

Comment: Please check if values of `col1`, `col2`, `col3` and `col4` are numbers. Correlation must be calculated on number, not on strings.

Comment: values are number. i have change HTML input type to "number" but it is still showing EmptyDataframe

Comment: Have you tried explicitly casting them to float, like this: `col1 = float(request.POST.get('col1'))` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check that those GET variables are not empty or not numbers.

Then try to use the float cast method like float(col1)